# Ubuntu 21.04 the repository «http://ppa.launchpad.net/snwh/ppa/ubuntu hirsute Release» does not have a realease file

Tags: apt, updates, sudo, repository, 21.04

I just installed Ubuntu Budgie 21.04 and i tried to do a sudo apt-get update but it gave me the next error:

```
sudo apt-get update
Obj:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/numix/ppa/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
Ign:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/snwh/ppa/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
Obj:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntubudgie/backports/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
Err:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/snwh/ppa/ubuntu hirsute Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho                
E: El repositorio «http://ppa.launchpad.net/snwh/ppa/ubuntu hirsute Release» no tiene un fichero de Publicación.
N: No se puede actualizar de un repositorio como este de forma segura y por tanto está deshabilitado por omisión.
N: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de repositorios y la configuración de usuarios.
```

The error in english says: The repository «http://ppa.launchpad.net/snwh/ppa/ubuntu hirsute Release» does not have a realease file

I tried lots of tutorials but nothing, other types of software downloads work fine, either from the terminal and software app, i really don't know what is wrong here. These are my installed PPA.

```
apt policy
$ ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d
Archivos de paquetes:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntubudgie/backports/ubuntu hirsute/main i386 Packages
     release v=21.04,o=LP-PPA-ubuntubudgie-backports,a=hirsute,n=hirsute,l=backports,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntubudgie/backports/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
     release v=21.04,o=LP-PPA-ubuntubudgie-backports,a=hirsute,n=hirsute,l=backports,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/numix/ppa/ubuntu hirsute/main i386 Packages
     release v=21.04,o=LP-PPA-numix,a=hirsute,n=hirsute,l=PPA for the Numix Project Ltd.,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/numix/ppa/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
     release v=21.04,o=LP-PPA-numix,a=hirsute,n=hirsute,l=PPA for the Numix Project Ltd.,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
Paquetes con pin:
$: orden no encontrada
```

Comment: PPA's are *personal package archives* or 3rd party sources, so all security checks, are they safe (security wise), appropriate for your release, well maintained etc are all on you.  A quick look at one of your messages shows *hirsute* was not a supported release for the PPA I looked at.

Comment: I understand, but what is the official repository for ubuntu hirsute updates? I can't find it anywhere

Comment: PPA's are not official repositories, but *personal package repositories* with the personal highlighting they're 3rd party and not official.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Comment: If you look at the supported releases at https://launchpad.net/~snwh/+archive/ubuntu/ppa you'll not *hirsute* is not there, all you can do is make a request of the owner to build for *hirsute*, but being a 3rd party source, the owner can build for whichever releases he/she decides to.

Comment: Managed to fix it, for some reason the terminal commands to delete the ppa didn't work but from synaptic i could. Thanks!